# How to cause variable stat changes over extended period?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I'm trying to create a wizard with a polymorph spell in Mutants and Masterminds 3rd edition. I want the power to have the ability to alter a target's stats in a number of different ways for an extended period (around half an hour will suffice).

- Using an Affliction that causes a transformation doesn't work, because it fades too quickly.
- I then tried making a Morph effect with Attack, Increased Duration (Continuous) and Metamorph, but Metamorph only allows for a limited number of stat changes.
- I tried filing it under a Variable power, but I'm not sure whether or not Continuous effects will remain when I swap powers so I'm assuming it won't to be safe.

Is there any way I can do this? If so, how?

Comment: Is there anything I can add to this for you, SilverGM?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to improve your ability to affect a target of similar PL with *Affliction*, from using *Extras* like *Cumulative*, *Progressive*, and *Concentration* to using *Weaken* to reduce their saves. But ultimately, the question I'd ask is whether it makes sense to be able to have that prolonged effect on a target of the same or higher PL. Working from the source material of comics, people are seldom transformed for long unless it's something plot-related. And, in that case it's generally a *GM Fiat* kind of situation. Against targets of a lower PL, well, that's more in keeping with the source material. You might be able to turn the Mayor into a hat rack and it will take him a long time to roll a successful save, especially if some of them have been debilitated by a *Weaken* effect.

For what it is worth, the answer would be different for a 2E game, where there were defined rules for how long an Alternate Effect remained for the various durations, but that was not something they transported over to 3E.

Ultimately, if you are the GM, do it as a *Fiat*. If you are not, talk to your GM and see what they find reasonable.